# Matching a word that is surrounded by any character with the exception of any valid word or being part of a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this small task at hand. I am required to match a word that is surrounded by any of the following characters [ \n\r\t!@#\$%*\^()_.,].

Sorry let me be clear about this. As of right now I am able to match "To", "*to*", "$to$', "#To#". However, if I search for "To_Lee" with the code below, it does not find it. I need to be able to match "To_Lee" but ignore any word that contains "to" in it like "tomato".

```
$string = 'This is a random string that contains To_Lee';
preg_match('/\b(_*(to)_*)\b/i', $string, $matches);
```

This will return true for all cases with the exception of To_Lee. Can someone please tell me what I need to do so that it can capture To_Lee as a valid match?

Sorry for the confusion, hope this is a bit clearer.

Thanks once again.

Comment: It doesn't make sense because you want to match what you call "words" delimited by certain characters. Now, both the words and delimiters can be _. How can you do that? Is "mike_tyson" a word ("mike_tyson") or is it two words ("mike" and "tyson")?

Comment: Also it would be much more helpful if you included in your example sample input and output i.e. in: "Mike mike_tyson _mike_tyson *mike* #mike" out: "Mike", "mike_tyson", "mike_tyson", "mike", "mike"

Comment: Moreover, I do hope you realise that looking for "mike" will not help you find "mike_tyson"

Comment: Please provide some actual example, I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry for that, I had to change the example to better fit my need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my own question. After testing the code on my environment I'm getting the results I am expecting.

After explaining what I wanted to Alexei, I essentially came to my answer.

Here is the code:

```
$string = 'This is a very long string, that contains Sam. sam is just as bad. Not sure what I need but i think it feels the same. Sam_Alex is the same as Alex_Sam. Alex is the same as well..';
```

***Essentially we want to match anything that is not a letter around to the specified string in the parenthesis. In the string above you noticed that I added the word "same" which is similar to "sam". However, this word is completely ignored, and in this case we want to ignore "same".***

```
$pattern = '([^a-zA-Z])(_*(Sam)_*)([^a-zA-Z])';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Gives us:

```
var_dump($mathes);
array(1 => "Sam.",2 => " sam", 3 => "Sam_", 4 => "_Sam");
```

Thanks for everyone's help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I thought you wanted to match words such as `sam`, `sam_bla_bla`, `bla_bla_sam`, `bla_sam_bla` when they are delimited by `\W` or `_`.